# HTML Form file upload and database insert

Tags: html, file-upload

I want to create a form in which i have some textfields and a field for a file upload.
In the action i upload the file first, and then save the values from the textfields in my database.

For a file upload I need enctype="multipart/form-data" and then it works but the other things does not work.
when i take the default enctype the data save works but the file upload failed.

What should I do?

Comment: How are you processing the form? ASP, PHP, CGI?

Comment: Do you have separate uploads? Do you use ajax calls when posting the form? Please elaborate, preferably with some code...

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data"  will not affect the value in your textarea. I think we can check it further if you could post more codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any HTML source?

The enctype should also POST the textfields to the server. Make sure you access the file by `$_FILES` and the other data by `$_POST`.

You do need `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

If theres still something wrong, it's not in your HTML.